# Wildcard in /etc/hosts file

Tags: hostname, hosts

It seems that wildcards are not supported in the /etc/hosts file.

What is the best solution for me to resolve all *.local domains to localhost?

Comment: What distro are you using?

Comment: @Mark Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: possible cross site duplicate of: http://serverfault.com/questions/118378/in-my-etc-hosts-file-on-linux-osx-how-do-i-do-a-wildcard-subdomain

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You'd really need to run your own DNS server and use wildcards.  Exactly how you'd do that would depend on the DNS package you ran.

Comment: Indeed.  This is rather trivial with dnsmasq; a configuration with address=/local/127.0.0.1 does what OP requests.